# Z-index with a relatively positioned element

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

I have a web page with a CSS dropdown navigation menu. My issue is that when I hover over the top of the menu to make the dropdowns appear, everything else in the page moves to make space for the dropdown instead of the dropdown moving over everything else. My navigation links are in a div element with the id "header" and my CSS for that element looks like this:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
```

None of the elements in the page that are moving are inside the header and non of them have a z-index specified. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position: absolute` to the submenus that appear when you hover over a menu button.

See here for a tutorial: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Also relevant: http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: This worked, but why do I need to use position absolute? I understood the specification as saying that z-index would work for elements that were positioned absolutely or relatively. Is that wrong or am I just misunderstanding it?

Comment: It's not a matter of `z-index`. You need `position: absolute` to remove the submenus from the normal document flow. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/mMGqd/

Answer (score 0):

Change `position` to `absolute` and make the `position` of the parent container `relative`.

Or, in the opposite direction, create another container within `#header` and stuff everything inside it.

The key point is that the inner element needs to be absolutely positioned, but in relation to its parent.  Therefore position parent relatively.

Comment: From my understanding, `#header` is the "parent container".

Comment: okay, then its children become absolutely positioned.  The answer is Oeneral enough to care of either way.